Cannot join two hair/curves objects
If I open a new file and add two "empty hair" objects to a plane, I am unable to join them into a single hair object after selecting both of them:

I remember this being possible before. I assume I'm doing something wrong because I can find no one else having this specific problem.


I think I tried that once before, but it didn't work. No idea why it doesn't work. But you can join them with a Geometry Nodes modifier. Add a Join Geometry node and select the other curve object to join the curves.
